# Encrypt Transformed Web Config

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, publishing

I am using visual studio click publishing to publish my site via FTP (Right click -> Publish -> FTP).

I want to encrypt the web.config as part of the publishing process.

I am following http://litemedia.info/encrypt-your-web-config-with-msbuild which is great, but it modifys the actual web.config file, which I don't want. I want to modify the project file to encrypt the TRANSFORMED web.config Prior to the publish.

I cannot find a target which is fired Post web.config transform, but prior to the FTP publish in order to do this.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Regards
Karl

Update - I have since answered my own question and found a target which is executed after the web.config is transformed, just before the physical file publish.

```
<Target Name="CustomPostPublishActions" AfterTargets="PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder" >
<Exec Command="&quot;%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe&quot; -pef &quot;connectionStrings&quot; &quot;$(WebProjectOutputDir)\obj\$(ConfigurationName)\TransformWebConfig\transformed&quot; -prov &quot;RsaProvider&quot;" />
</Target>
```

Comment: what does it have to do with ClickOnce?